# JavaScript - uncheck check box on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to implement a simple 'show password' toggle check box so that whilst the mouse is held down, the plain text password is shown, and once it's let go it reverts back to a password field.

I've got the toggle of the `input` field working, however I'm using a check box to show the toggle state as well, and I can check the box on `mousedown` however my attempt at then unchecking the box is not quite working.

Here's what I've got so far;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vnX6q/1/)

```
var pwi = $('#new_pass');

$('.pw_show').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('.pw_show input').prop('checked', true);
    pwi.prop('type', 'text');
});

$('.pw_show').on('mouseup', function () {
    pwi.prop('type', 'password');
    setTimeOut(function() {
        $('.pw_show input').prop('checked', false);
    }, 50);
});
```

This *almost* works, however if the user double clicks quickly then they can *break* it leaving the checkbox checked.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may try after removing the `SetTimeOut()` function call in the `mouseup` event.

Comment: The function name is `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut`. Also note that for security reasons most browsers do not allow changing `type` property of the inputs.

Comment: @undefined doh! That was enough to fix it...silly me

Comment: should use 'change' listener on the checkbox instead of 'mousedown' and 'mouseup'

Comment: @Hacketo presumably that would only work after clicking and letting go as the check box state by default doesn't change until the mouse click has bee released.

Comment: @undefined feel free to write that as an answer if you'd like the rep. That fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was the spelling of the `setTimeout` function. After fixing this, the small delay I added, allowed the check box to be checked and unchecked on click hold and release.

```
$('.pw_show').on('mouseup', function () {
    pwi.prop('type', 'password');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.pw_show input').prop('checked', false);
    }, 50);
});
```

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnX6q/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".pw_show input").attr("checked","");
```

Comment: That is essentially the same as `$('.pw_show input').prop('checked', false);` and is not the issue. I have fixed the issue as per undefined's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly, but this works only for `.pw_show`. So if you `mouseup` at the another layer, it does not work. I noticed that your Input has not stable width.

You can either use removeAttr:

```
$(".pw_show input").removeAttr("checked");
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, however I had already tried using `removeAttr()` it was however not the issue. My spelling of the timeout function was the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use change event in jquery to to check a check box ,based on that you change the text box type

```
    var pwi = $('#new_pass');
      $('.pw_show').find("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
           pwi.prop("type", (this.checked) ? "text" : "password");

      });
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vnX6q/2/)

If you want mousedown and mouse up,use like this

```
 var pwi = $('#new_pass');

$('.pw_show').find("input[type=checkbox]").mousedown('change', function () {
    pwi.prop("type",  "text" );

});
$('.pw_show').find("input[type=checkbox]").mouseup('change', function () {

    pwi.prop("type",  "password");

});
```

### [USING MOUSEDOWN/MOUSEUP](http://jsfiddle.net/vnX6q/6/)

Comment: @Novocaine88 pls check my demo If you not satisfied other answer

Comment: This is not the functionality I'm after. I wanted the check box and password shown/hidden on click *hold* and then revert once the mouse has been released. This answer only gives a click on/off toggle. I have however got the answer I needed from undefineds comment. I simply spelt the time out function incorrectly.

Comment: @Novocaine88 .Ok i was  misunderstanding of your question,anyway you got solution :)