# Checkbox on mousedown, uncheck on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, preventdefault, jquery-events

I am making jQuery application where there is a checkbox that is checked only when the mouse/key/touch is pressed. Check on mousedown, uncheck on mouseup.

Even if I use `event.preventDefault()`, the checkbox remains checked if the mouse button is not down, but the spacebar works fine.

```js
$(function() {
  var cb = $("input");
  cb
    .on("mousedown keydown", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      cb.prop("checked", true);
    })
    .on("mouseup keyup", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      cb.prop("checked", false);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=checkbox autofocus>
```

I know the code above needs a bit of work to work correctly in any situation (touch, etc.) but it is written for testing purposes only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - uncheck check box on mouseup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993978/javascript-uncheck-check-box-on-mouseup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `click` event fires when `mouseup` is released on the checkbox and this forces the `checked` property to `true`. To fix this hook an event handler to the `click` and simply call `preventDefault()` on it.

Also note that you can provide an object to `on()` which is keyed by the event names you want to hook to, instead of calling `on()` multiple times:

```js
$(function() {
  var $cb = $("input");
  $cb.on({
    "mousedown keydown": function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $cb.prop("checked", true);
    },
    "mouseup keyup": function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $cb.prop("checked", false);
    },
    'click': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=checkbox autofocus>
```

Alternatively, as @enapupe pointed out in the comments, you could remove the `mouseup` event handler entirely and let the default `click` event run as normal to toggle the state of the checkbox:

```js
$(function() {
  var $cb = $("input");
  $cb.on({
    "mousedown keydown": function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $cb.prop("checked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=checkbox autofocus>
```

Either will work, it just depends on the behaviour you want to have with regard to suppressing the `click` event

Comment: Funny, another option is cutting the mouseup part and letting click do its thing, works as well.

Comment: @enapupe that's a very good point, thanks. I added a note about it to the answer.